# how to create array that will print_r like this: array( array('foo' => 'bar'))

Tags: php

how to create array that will print_r like this:

```
array( array('foo' => 'bar'))
```

because this:

```
$a = array( array('foo' => 'bar'))
```

will print this:

```
Array( [0] => Array ('foo' => 'bar'))
```

Comment: `array( array('foo' => 'bar'))` is the same exact thing as `Array( [0] => Array ('foo' => 'bar'))`

Comment: @Mike thank you very much. (if you are not ashamed by anwering this kind of questions go and answer, i will accept that.)

Comment: I don't really have time right now. If someone else wants to answer it, go ahead and accept their answer. Or you can answer your own question if you want as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print_r` always prints arrays by showing the indexes explicitly. There's no way to customize this. So even if it's a normal indexed array, it will show all the numeric indexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
array( array('foo' => 'bar'))
```

is the same exact thing as

```
Array( [0] => Array ('foo' => 'bar'))
```

Also, `var_dump($array_var);` should do a similarly nice pretty-print for you.